# How to change folder Winston logs at runtime?

Tags: node.js, winston

I am currently using winston logger in my Node.js app:

```
transports: [
            new (DailyRotateFile)({
                filename: '%DATE%_info.log',
                dirname: resolve(__dirname, '..', 'logs', moment().format(process.env.LOG_DATE_FORMAT)),
                datePattern: process.env.LOG_DATETIME_FORMAT,
                format: format.combine(format.prettyPrint(), format.timestamp()),
                maxSize: '10m',
                level: 'info'
            })
        ],
```

I want logs for each day be put in the respective folders but thats not the case, the folders get changed only when the app restarts but folder for e.g. `12-Dec-2018` will contain logs of 12th, 13th, ...

So how do I make it change folders at runtime, e.g. during each rotation it updates the dirname as well, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually decided to write my own mini library to do this work for me, it's simple and light; [wow-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wow-logger).